# Location of Disk Utility created volume?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, monterey

Upon creating a new volume via Disk Utility in macOS (12.2 Monterey), where does the actual DMG file get created / live? (aside from the mount point /Volumes/newvolume - is there a DMG file somewhere, that I can backup / transfer to another machine? AFPS encrypted, if that matters)

Comment: It's not clear what [or how] you created this. A volume is not a disk image - though a mounted disk image contains a volume. Please add detail of precisely how you achieved this.

Comment: Within Disk Utility, I used the + (add) button to "Add APFS volume to container?" - so I suppose it's a volume?  Does that mean there's no physical file to backup/transfer?

(EDIT): I see now how to create an image and pick its location, so I can do that as an alternative, but I'm still wondering, is there a physical file for the volume, or would I just mount it and then back up the files within it to something like an external disk?  Is there any major advantage to using a volume vs an image?

Comment: @lioman Correct, you've created a new volume, which is more similar to a partition than a disk image - Volumes are created within an APFS Container which occupies a partition on your disk. Volumes share that space between themselves.

Comment: There's no physical file for the volume - just the same as there's no physical file for your regular boot volume. A Disk Image, once mounted, can be filled with data  just like a regular volume, then once unmounted can then be transferred to another Mac, where it can then be mounted… just like a regular volume.